# PHP cURL as DELETE using POSTFIELDS

Tags: api, rest, php-curl, http-delete

In my case the user is logged in and would like to delete his account.
Therfore he triggers a POST form, revalidating the process with a confirmation of his password.

Now I would like to send a cURL DELETE to the api/server and at the same time deliver the confirmed password as well.

My approach is:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
    CURLOPT_URL => "https://www.myurl.com/v1/users",
    CURLOPT_USERAGENT => $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT],
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => json_encode(['cnfpwd' => $_POST['cnfpwd']]), //confirmed password
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array('X-API-KEY: '$apiKey),
    CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
    CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
    CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
    CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
    CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "DELETE",
));

$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
$data = json_decode($response, true);

//For testing purposes only
print_r($response);
print_r($data);
```

If this approach is correct, how would I get the POSTFIELDS on the API/server side?
As this is a DELETE request, $_GET, $_POST, $_REQUEST are empty.

EDIT:
The api code for testing purposes:

```
<?php
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "DELETE"){
   echo"POST: ";print_r($_POST);
}
?>
```

The result is:

> POST: Array ( )

Comment: If you do an DELETE request, you will find your data in $_POST

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to get the **body** of the request with

```
$data = file_get_contents('php://input');
```

Comment: I am deleting the account, it is just that I would like to pass the confirmed password, like: "Do you really want to delete your account, please enter your password again", so DELETE is correct in this case.

Comment: @daniel in this case, yes, `DELETE` is the proper verb

Answer (score 0):

My final solution is:

```
$parameters = file_get_contents("php://input");
$parameters = json_decode($parameters, true);
```

@Paolos Solution is correct, I just needed to add the second line in order to access the parameters as an Array.